# python dict in list on for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I don't understand why these 2 statements is not equal.

```
for item in tree.findAll('item'):
    names = [{
      'id': item.id.string,
      'title': __decodefunction(item.entitle.string)
    }]
```

it has 1 item
but if these statement

```
names = [{
    'id': item.id.string,
    'title': __decodefunction(item.entitle.string)
}for item in tree.findAll('item')]
```

it has 6 items.

I want to use first loop, but it does not show me the correct number of items. The correct output is 6 items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They do very different things.

The first defines a new `names` value in each iteration of the loop, replacing any previous value. Each time you create a new list with *one* dictionary in it.

The second is a list comprehension, which builds a list consisting of 0 or more dictionaries, one for each element returned by `tree.findAll()`.

To make the first one equivalent to the second, you'd need to define `names` as an empty list first, then append to it in the loop:

```
names = []
for item in tree.findAll('item'):
    names.append({
      'id': item.id.string,
      'title': __decodefunction(item.entitle.string)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I got that

just change to this

```
names = []
for item in tree.findAll('item'):
    names.extend([{
       'id': item.id.string,
       'title': __decodefunction(item.entitle.string)
    }])
```

Comment: The `.extend([])` part is not needed; you are only adding one element at a time, so `.append()` is more effective.

Comment: While you have two solutions which work one like the other, I would suggest you use the other one, called list comprehension. It looks more handy and pythonic to me.